# Changing cursor type from python

Tags: python, windows-terminal

I am making a text based video game with python, and I need a way to change the cursor type from inside python. Here is my code:

```py
from os import system,getenv
from json import loads,dumps
import uuid
apd = getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")
pf = loads(open(rf"{apd}\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json").read())
pf['profiles']['list'].append({"guid":str(uuid.uuid4()),'name':"Game","commandline": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe","cursorShape": "vintage","font": {"face": "Consolas"},})
open(rf"{apd}\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json",'w').write(dumps(pf))
system('wt -F -d {{PATH TO FILE}} -p "Game" --title Game python game.py')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a great idea to place a dependency on Windows Terminal, but if you do go that route, the right way to do this is via the [JSON fragment extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/json-fragment-extensions) feature.

Don't risk modifying the user's Windows Terminal settings file directly via Python.  Users will be quite (rightly) upset if you muck up *their* settings if something goes wrong.

JSON fragment extensions give you the ability to create a separate settings fragment that *only* applies to your application/profile.

For example, create a fragment:

```
{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "My Game",
      "commandline": "python.exe /path/to/game.py",
      "cursorShape": "vintage",
      "font": {"face": "Consolas"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Place this file in either:

- `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\Fragments\{app-name}\{file-name}.json`:  For all users on the system
- `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\Fragments\{app-name}\{file-name}.json`:  For only the current user